# Regarding the conflict of JsonValue class names in springboot and mysql driver packages

Tags: java, mysql, spring

question:
when start springboot, I got the error message: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'jsonValue' for bean class [com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.JsonValue] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue]

版本信息：

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.33</version>
</dependency>

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
</parent>
</dependency>
```

Obviously, this is a conflict between the com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue used by springboot and the com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.JsonValue class name in the mysql driver package, and I cannot rule out one of these two , because they are used; and I can't modify these two classes; I tried downgrading the version, but it will introduce other problems. Want to know how do you solve this situation? Thanks.

Obviously, this is a conflict between the com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue used by springboot and the com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.JsonValue class name in the mysql driver package, and I cannot rule out one of these two , because they are used; and I can't modify these two classes; I tried downgrading the version, but it will introduce other problems. Want to know how do you solve this situation? Thanks.